# What is IndexError returned by Py2neo?

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

When I run a cypher query using Py2neo, I got the following error message. I don't really understand what it means. I am guessing that a connection to the database is closed or broken for some reasons. Could you help me understand this message?
To be clear, this is a part of my code. `neo4jDB` is a graph object. `cypher_query` is a string of a cypher.  `neo4jDB.run(cypher_query).data()` returns a list of dictionaries.

`cypher_query` looks like this `'MATCH (n:node) <-[:relationship]-(another:another node) WHERE n.id='12345' AND another.id='12345' RETURN  another.x, another.y, another.z, another.w limit 1'`

A part of my code

```
if len(neo4jDB.run(cypher_query).data()) == 0:
        no_records.append(id)
```

Error Message

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2neo\client\__init__.py in acquire(self, force_reset, can_overfill)
    791                 # Plan A: select a free connection from the pool
--> 792                 cx = self._free_list.popleft()
    793             except IndexError:

IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-439-a052dd2ba35c> in <module>
----> 7     if len(neo4jDB.run(cypher_query).data()) == 0:
      8         no_records.append(id)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2neo\database.py in run(self, cypher, parameters, **kwparameters)
    403         :return:
    404         """
--> 405         return self.auto().run(cypher, parameters, **kwparameters)
    406 
    407     def evaluate(self, cypher, parameters=None, **kwparameters):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2neo\database.py in run(self, cypher, parameters, **kwparameters)
    976                 result = self._connector.run(self.ref, cypher, parameters)
    977             else:
--> 978                 result = self._connector.auto_run(cypher, parameters,
    979                                                   graph_name=self.graph.name,
    980                                                   readonly=self.readonly)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2neo\client\__init__.py in auto_run(self, cypher, parameters, pull, graph_name, readonly)
   1336             cx = self._acquire_ro(graph_name)
   1337         else:
-> 1338             cx = self._acquire_rw(graph_name)
   1339         try:
   1340             result = cx.auto_run(cypher, parameters, graph_name=graph_name, readonly=readonly)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2neo\client\__init__.py in _acquire_rw(self, graph_name)
   1238                 log.debug("Using connection pool %r", pool)
   1239                 try:
-> 1240                     cx = pool.acquire()
   1241                 except (ConnectionUnavailable, ConnectionBroken):
   1242                     self.prune(pool.profile)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2neo\client\__init__.py in acquire(self, force_reset, can_overfill)
    797                     # ConnectionUnavailable exception, which
    798                     # should bubble up to the caller.
--> 799                     cx = self.connect()
    800                     if cx.supports_multi():
    801                         self._supports_multi = True

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2neo\client\__init__.py in connect(self)
    743             cx = self._opened_list.popleft()
    744             if cx.closed or cx.broken:
--> 745                 self._bytes_sent += cx.bytes_sent
    746                 self._bytes_received += cx.bytes_received
    747             else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2neo\client\__init__.py in bytes_sent(self)
    209     @property
    210     def bytes_sent(self):
--> 211         raise NotImplementedError
    212 
    213     @property

NotImplementedError:
```

Comment: What returns a print of `neo4jDB.run(cypher_query).data ())` ?
And what contains your string cypher_query ?

Comment: It returns a list of dictionaries. It contains up to one dictionary because the cypher limits the number of items returned to 1. I cannot tell you what the Cypher is exactly, but it looks like this....'MATCH (n:node) <-[:relationship]-(another:another node) WHERE n.id='12345' AND another.id='12345' RETURN  another.x, another.y, another.z, another.w limit 1'

Comment: Is `another node` really a node type in your graph?

Comment: @AdrianKeister yes it is.

Comment: Are spaces allowed in node type names? I highly doubt that.

Comment: I would try your query in the browser interface or the cypher-query command line interface, and make sure it's returning what you expect, before you try the `py2neo` or, what I would recommend, the `neo4j` driver.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Sorry. No, white spaces are not allowed. It is an example. I needed to pay attention to the details of it. By the way, I finally solved that problem. It looks like that my connection to the database is disconnected after certain hours if I do not reconnect to the database